# How to specify correctly codebase and archive in Java applet?

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I use firefox version > 3.5 (3.5.*,3.6.*,4.*) and I try to specify `archive` and `codebase` property correctly but it doesn't work. My main class for applet is situated in the `archive` and some necessary classes that are loaded during runtime are situated in the `codebase`. If I specify only the `archive` then the applet is loaded but the classes from `codebase` are missing. If I specify the `archive` and the `codebase` then the applet can't be loaded. It looks like applet try to load main class from `codebase` folder and doesn't look into the `archive` file.

```
<html>    
<body>
<applet width=600 height=300 code="MyClass.class" 
  type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=6" 
  archive="http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar" 
  codebase="http://myurl.com/classes">
    no applet
</applet>
</body>    
</html>
```

Main class is situated in http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar and runtime classes are situated in http://myurl.com/classes.

Comment: Show us your short but complete example HTML, along with a description of the directory structure containing each of the resources.

Comment: There is an option (with a `param` tag inside the `applet` tag) to switch the `codebase` off. I believe the old MRJ on the Mac, always ignored the `codebase` if you had an `archive`. / Not sure if the `codebase` requires a trailing `/`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Attribute `codebase` specifies the base URL of the applet - the directory that contains the applet's code. It is used while searching jar files in `archive` attribute, in such a way that all jars in `archive` attribute are searched relative to `codebase`.
So. When you use `archive="http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar"` and `codebase="http://myurl.com/classes"` together it means: find **"http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar"** in **"http://myurl.com/classes"** folder.
I.e. the full search path is **"http://myurl.com/classes/http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar"**. And of course it can't be found!
Also, classes, whose jar-files aren't specified in the `archive` attribute, can't be found without `codebase` attribute. I.e. if there is no `codebase` then there is no way to find your classes in **"http://myurl.com/classes"** folder.

You can find more details in the [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html) tutorial.

I suggest the following **solution**:

1. Place `myjar.jar` in the `http://myurl.com/classes` folder;
2. Assuming your MyClass.class is in *default* package, and in the **"http://myurl.com/archive/myjar.jar"**, the following code should work:

---

```
<html>    
<body>
<applet width=600 height=300 code="MyClass" 
  type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=6" 
  archive="myjar.jar" 
  codebase="http://myurl.com/classes">
   no applet
</applet>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Great answer.  :)  Re. `classes` directory.  I find that confusing & prefer `lib` (which is also shorter ;) ).  The `type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=6"` also reminded me of [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to handle the ugly details of deciding exactly what to write according to browser (& browser version) & OS.

Comment: `classes` directory was suggested only to give the faster solution in given conditions. :) Of course `lib` dir should be used instead.

Comment: *"give the faster solution in given conditions"*  If the matter were 'service within 6 hours' the OP could not have any complaints.  ;)  Your answer immediately(1) got my +1.  :)  1) Well 'immediately' after I saw it and probably before making the comment.

Comment: @JakeGould Please, do not touch the post if you do not know how to properly format it. Your edit made html invisible!

Comment: @JakeGould It's a bypass. I don't remember why. It just worked for me. If you can find the answer yourself, please, let me know.