# Applet can't find classes in weblogic 11

Tags: java, applet, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have an applet and a few libraries in jar files. Obviously, all required classes are deployed with my applet as I added them to library path in my IDE (JDeveloper). But it can't access these classes. The applet just freeze ups without any errors. Maybe it caused by security permissions ? Here is a structure in deployment archive (war)

```
WEB-INF
    classes
      my
      other_packages
    lib
      jar libs are here
applet.html
my
  package of classes, don't know why it is duplicated
```

Here is HTML file:

```
<APPLET CODE="my.base.Applet1"  
 HEIGHT="200" WIDTH="200" MAYSCRIPT ALIGN="bottom">This browser does not support Applets.
</APPLET>
```

I tried to add jar libraries and it works only if I open html file with applet from local disk. I have to specify path to libraries as ARCHIVE="WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar". If I use just "commons-logging.jar" as it was in official tutorials it causes "Class not found" error.
So  it can't find these jar files even with ARCHIVE="WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar" when deployed on server and accessed through http.

I use JDeveloper and deploy html, applet and libraries as a war file to Weblogic 11.

I also tried CODEBASE attribute both with CODEBASE="/bea_wls_internal/classes/" and with additional "appName@componentName" specified
CODEBASE="/bea_wls_internal/classes/appName@componentName". Maybe I use "appName@componentName" wrong but there are only few not clear examples how to use it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet/5950258#5950258).

Answer (score 0):

Resources in `WEB-INF` are private to the server.  Those resources are not offered up to browsers.

You can check this by typing an ('http:' or 'https:' prefixed) URL pointing to a resource in the `WEB-INF` into your browser's address bar and hitting enter.