# Java applet: How to tell the browser (Firefox) where to look for libraries (jars)

Tags: java, firefox, jar, applet

I have written a Java applet class and made a small HTML page to include it via the <applet>-tag.
(This is running locally on my disk drive for the moment)
This works well, that is, the applet is being loaded properly.
But the applet depends on external libraries (jars).
E.g. i imported org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas;
Of course, I have all the jars here and testing the applet from within Eclipse works fine.
But the browser (Firefox) doesn't seem to find the jars.
How do i tell the browser where to search for the external jars?
I tried setting CLASSPATH in the user environment variables. without success.
This is on windows XP, running JRE 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applet is executed in clients machine, so having libs in CLASSPATH won't help.

Libs should be in "archive" attribute:

```
<applet code="Applet.class" archive="myApplet.jar,lib1.jar,lib2.jar" width="600" height="600" title="MyApplet">
```

Comment: Yes, the libs are in the archive attribute:
archive="batik-swing.jar" (amongst others)
(forgot to mention that, sorry)

But the browser doesn't seem to find them (how would it know the path?):

Browser's Java console says:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/swing/JSVGCanvas

Comment: Good question.
Tried with IE8. Doesn't work either.
But in IE i can't even access the Java console, so i don't know if it's the same error reason.

Comment: @Scrontch "how would it know the path?" You set path in "archive" attribute. In my example, all 3 jars must be in the same dir. You can set different paths. For example archive="myApplet.jar,../libs/lib1.jar,../libs/lib2.jar"

Comment: Ok, so i'm trying to give a complete path in the archive attribute now.
But now i get an
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
The (Windows) file path on my machine is D:\Dev\batik-1.7.
I tried replacing back-slahes with forward-slahes but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Ok, i have copied the jars over to some other location and using relative paths now (../lib/). This seems to work. I have other unsatisfied dependencies now, but that's another issue.

Comment: @Scrontch Applets are designed to be distributed entirely over the NETWORK at launch time, so you are simply NOT ALLOWED to specify files on the filesystem of either the client or the server. It doesn't make sense. I hope that helps to explain why Java didn't understand your paths when you tried using a filename instead of a URI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `codebase` attribute of the `applet` tag.

Have a look at [how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet/5950258#5950258).

It is similar to your question.