# Where to put mysql connector in directory for applet connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, applet, mysql-connector

I am using the Java MySql connector so that my applet can access a database on my site. However, it is not working because the error is returning null when trying to use the connector, which does not happen when I run it from eclipse.
So, should the connector jar file be packaged inside the jar that's generated for my applet or should it be outside of the applet's jar in the same directory, or somewhere else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068658/java-applet-how-to-tell-the-browser-firefox-where-to-look-for-libraries-jars

Comment: *"so that my applet can access a database on my site."*  For the security of the DB, it should ***not*** be accessible to every Tom, Dick & Applet that wanders by!

Comment: @AndrewThompson so what do i do? use a servlet?

Comment: *"use a servlet?"*  Yes.  That is one way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is that the easiest way?

Comment: *"Is that the easiest way?"* If you know PHP best - PHP, ditto. ASP ditto servlets..