# jar file download location / how can I tell if the classpath isn't right?

Tags: java, jar, codebase

Ugh - I'm having to work on something I know little about, so I'm not sure I'm even searching for the right thing.

I have a java applet being served by my website (internal to the company only, unfortunately) and I'm getting a Class Not Found error when folks are accessing it using JRE 1.7/Java 7.  It works with JRE 1.6/Java 6.

It works perfectly if I call a demonstration page locally via a browser, when all of the files are in the same folder:

```
APPLET CODEBASE = "./"
ARCHIVE  = "my.jar"
CODE     = "my.class"
NAME     = "Test"
WIDTH    = 400
HEIGHT   = 150
COL      = 7
HSPACE   = 0
VSPACE   = 0
ALIGN    = top
```

But what I don't know/understand is when a browser has the JVM download a JAR file - and I'm not certain that my 7 clients *are* downloading the JAR file - where do those files go?  Are they named the same thing?  (If they are, and the name is the same, then I *know* that the files aren't being downloaded, which would explain a lot.  Of course, then I need to figure out why they aren't on 7 but are on 6. *sigh*)  Since I can't figure out where those files go, I can't tell if my CODEBASE path is correct, which I think is the actual problem.  I can't find the answer via google - but it may be that the question is so basic that the answer isn't out there, or I'm just not looking for the right thing.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet - the codebase must be a URL

Comment: Interesting - I saw that entry earlier but didn't catch that the codebase had to be an absolute URL path and not a relative one.  So I've made that change, and tested the URL to ensure that the file is accessible.  I put a packet analyzer on my workstation and I see the request going out to the server for the my.jar file, and it appears to download properly.

However, it still isn't executing & Java control panel / view doesn't show it.  I've changed the security settings in Java to no avail; it's like there's a disconnect between the download and the (I guess it's the) JRE?

Comment: If on the server side the classes where compiled for 1.7 there would be a class version error when the client can only read 1.6. One can however compile with Java 1.7 for say 1.5. But that is the other way around when I understand. **Another issue, is that the HTML applet tag is deprecated in favor of the object tag, as standard now in HTML5.** Give that a try.

Comment: So now my HTML reads like (per http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp)


<OBJECT 
CODEBASE="http://myserver/javascript"
ARCHIVE="my.jar"
CODE="mycode"
NAME="TestApplet"
ALIGN=middle
WIDTH=200 
HEIGHT=70>
</OBJECT>

and I don't even get the box throwing the java error any more - I'm getting nothing at all where the applet should be running.  I'm not getting a class version error - it's not registering the download of the JAR file, so there's no class comparison that could fail yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...

<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="150" width="400">
    <param name="code" value="My" />
    <param name="archive" value="my.jar" />
    No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

for a `public class My extends JApplet`.