# ClassNotFoundException - java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a java web server. One html page serves a java applet! I tested the html file without using the server, it works fine. the html file is placed with a folder named  "applets" containing the ".class"

example

.html

```
<applet code="applets/init.class" width="80%" height="80%> </applet>
```

My problem is when i pass it through the java server, i get error

```
ClasNotFoundException
applets.init.class
```

I have successfully downloaded the .class directly through the browser, which means the server is serving the .class.

Why does the server search for the .class at "applets.init.class" when the actual path is "applets/init.class"

Comment: See [how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet/5950258#5950258) for the answer.

Comment: See this link for the class not found exception  in applet

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690837/class-not-found-exception-on-applet/17690889#17690889][1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
<applet code="init" codebase="applets/" width="80%" height="80%"> </applet>
```

Also note the missing `"` to close the height.

Comment: It does not work:

ClassNotFoundException
init