# class not found exception on applet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, applet

I am trying to load applet on browser using html `<APPLET>` tag under `index.jsp` page in eclipse.

```
<APPLET archive="VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar" code ="vitaltrackapplet_mod/VitalTrackApplet_MOD.class"
                    width="100%" height="650">

    <PARAM name="opdid" value="1234" />
    <PARAM name="patientid" value="12" />
    <PARAM name="replay" value="false" />
    <PARAM name="hostpname" value="lifecare" />
    <PARAM name="pname" value="anil" />
    <PARAM name="createdate" value="12/17/2012" />
    <PARAM name="filename" value="example" />

</APPLET>
```

I have put **VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar** under **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib** folder.
but when I run this index.jsp every time it show `class not found excepion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run your `index.jsp` it find `VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar` under same folder. Please put your `VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar` under WebContent folder.

Comment: please check version for jre for your system and VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar

Comment: I used jre 1.6 and VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar was complied under 1.7

Comment: @VijayRamani  The JRE version is not relevant to a 'class not found' problem.  If it is not found in 1.6, it won't be found in 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

> ..put VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/lib/VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar
```

If you change `localhost:8080` & try that URL in the browser address bar you might note the server refuses to supply the Jar that is in a directory explicitly intended for the server side of a web-app. (I.E. **not** the client JRE).

The fix is to move the Jar (and codebase) to a place where any client can access it.

Comment: VitalTrackApplet_MOD.jar already under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: ..`WEB-INF/lib`..  See the edit to answer.   Move it out of there or it won't work!

Comment: BTW - copy/paste the URL that is used to access the `.jsp`