# Creating a Java applet that will display in a web browser

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, applet

I'm trying to create a basic Java applet that will display the output of my Java program in a web browser.

Having never worked with applets before, I thought I would follow a tutorial to try and create a simple "Hello World" applet, just to get a simple understanding of how they work.

I am using the example at: http://www.cs.nccu.edu.tw/~linw/javadoc/tutorial/getStarted/applet/index.html and have followed the steps exactly as described.

However, when I compile the Java source file, although a "HelloWorld" class file appears in my 'Project Explorer' window in Eclipse, I cannot see the class file at all when viewing the root project folder in Windows Explorer- all I see there is my HelloWorld.java file, and Hello.html file.

When I run the HelloWorld.java class in Eclipse, although I get a warning in the console that says:

```
Warning: Can't read AppletViewer properties file: C:.... Using defaults
```

the application does run- and a little window pops up titled "AppletViewer:...HellowWorld.class". This window has an 'Applet' menu, with menu items such as Restart, Reload, Stop, Save, etc, and the window displays "Hello World!" in the location specified, and a message saying "Applet started." at the bottom.

But, when I try to view the webpage in a browser, I get a message that says: "Error. Click for details" where the "Hello World" message should be displayed...

My HelloWorld.java class has the code:

```
package openDis.applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorld extends java.applet.Applet {
    public void init() {
        resize(150,25);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 50, 25);
    }
}
```

and the HTML in the webpage I'm trying to use to display the message is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Simple Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Here is the output of the program:

        <applet code="HelloWorld.class" width=150 height=25></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to get the output of the program to display in the web page? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) example to your post.

Comment: Sorry- I'm not sure how to do this? All of the code I currently have is copied into the question exactly as is (I've only just started this project, and just wanted to get some output from my program displaying in a web page to ensure that it works before I go any further.

Comment: When I click the error message in the browser, to see the details, it says it's getting a 'ClassNotFoundException'. I can see the class file in Eclipse though... so it should be there.

Comment: You need to properly specify the `codebase` attribute of the applet tag. Have a look at [how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet/5950258#5950258). You'll find the answer there.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: `resize(150,25);` The size of an applet is set in HTML.  The applet code should not try to enforce a size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..have followed the steps exactly as described.

No you didn't.  Their applet is in the default package, while yours is in `openDis.applet` package.

So:

```html
<applet code = "HelloWorld.class" width = 150 height = 25>
</applet>
```

Should be:

```html
<applet code = "openDis.applet.HelloWorld" width = 150 height = 25>
</applet>
```

And the structure needs to be:

- `dir` (directory)

  - `applet.html`
  - `openDis` (directory)

    - `applet` (directory)

      - `HelloWorld.class`

Comment: @MockerTim  I probably do it [too often](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers).  ;)

Comment: Sorry- missed that completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code attribute of the applet tag should not contain the `.class` extension.
It must contain the class name only. 
You also need to properly specify the codebase attribute of the applet tag.
Have a look at the [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html) tutorial for details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've got rid of the `.class` extension, as you suggested, and looked through the tutorial you linked to, trying what it suggested, and I can now get the Hello World applet running and displaying in a popup window when I run the class directly from Eclipse... But I'm still getting the same error when trying to view the applet in the browser- i.e. the 'error: click for details' message. I noticed that in the code example in the link you provided, it is referencing a JAR file-

Comment: I assume I will need to create my own? I've tried to do this, following the steps at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm but I'm still having the same issue when trying to view the page in a browser... any suggestions?

Comment: @someone2088 You don't need to create the jar file, unless you have more then one class.

Comment: Ok- but I've tried it without the jar file, and I'm still having the same issue- i.e. the "Error: click for details" message

Comment: @someone2088 And what happens when you click that message?

Comment: I get a 'ClassNotFoundException'... clicking that error opens a 'Java Console' popup window which lists a load of options such as "c: clear console window", "f: finalise objects on finalisation queue".

Comment: Interestingly, I've just noticed that the popup window states my computer's username as its home directory- not the folder I'm working from, which is a few levels down- could this be why it's not finding the class? If so, how do I specify the folder that my classes are saved in as the one for it to search in?

Comment: @someone2088 Have you added the codebase attribute to your applet tag?

Comment: The only attribute I currently have attached to my applet tag is the 'code' one- is 'codebase' different? What should I be looking to assign to the 'codebase' attribute?

Comment: @someone2088 Have a look at Andrew Thompson's answer.

Comment: @someone2088 About codebase you can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm) and in the SO post, I gave you the link to earlier ([how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet/5950258#5950258)). And you can google for it, of course.