# Troubles with applets in c# application

Tags: java, c#, applet

I'm trying to run some applets in a web application developed with c# and when I run it, I get this message:

`ClassNotFoundException .PruebaPulsacion.class`

I have checked some questions here but they doesn't work for me and I don't know what to do. **In my aspx page I have this piece of code:**

```
<applet codebase="http://etao-inico.usal.es/applets/paqApplet/"code="PruebaPulsacion.class" archive="etao4.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xml-apis.jar" width="100%" height="100%">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literalParametros"></asp:Literal>
</applet>
```

The structure which I have is what you can see on this graphic:

```
   /
    -applets
           --paqApplets
                ---PruebaPulsacion.class
                ---etao4.jar
                ---.......class
```

So as you can check in my codebase I have the url where the class are and as well I have put on all jars inside of this folder but nothing. I have followed this question: [How to specify correctly codebase and archive in Java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet)! but it doesn't work. Could you help me?, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the path of the code. Finally I removed the codebase and I wrote the next lines:

```
 <applet code="paqApplet/PruebaPulsacion.class" archive="http://etao-inico.usal.es/etao4.jar,http://etao-inico.usal.es/xercesImpl.jar,http://etao-inico.usal.es/xml-apis.jar" width="100%" height="100%">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literalParametros"></asp:Literal>
</applet>
```