# Java applet --> ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, exception, applet, directory, classnotfound

I'm learning Java and reading this book: https://www.fca.pt/cgi-bin/fca_main.cgi/?op=2&isbn=978-972-722-791-4.

In this book, I have a Java applet exercise. I can run it in Eclipse in appletviewer and works well. but I'm having trouble integrating the applet into HTML.

Here's my java code:

```
package packageteste;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Date;

public class Relogio extends Applet implements Runnable{


    Date data;
    Thread proc;
    Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40);

    public void start(){

        proc = new Thread(this);
        proc.start();

    }

    public void stop(){

        proc = null;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        while(proc == th){

            data = new Date();

            try{

                th.sleep(500);

            }catch(InterruptedException e){}

            repaint();

        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setFont(f);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString(data.toString(),20,60);
    }}
```

And now here's my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>


<body>
<applet code = "packageteste.Relogio.class" width="700"></applet>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Which class can't be found?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `code = "packageteste.Relogio.class"` must not include `.class`
- If you have your applet built into a `.jar` file use the `archive="..."` attribute to tell the browser what .jar it is.
- If you don't have a .jar make sure the class `packageteste.Relogio` can be found as `Relogio.class` in the `packageteste` directory.

See also here: [How to specify correctly codebase and archive in Java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947063/how-to-specify-correctly-codebase-and-archive-in-java-applet)

Comment: Note 2 things. 1) An applet that is not digitally signed will have almost no chance of being successfully launched in a modern JRE.  To be signed, code needs to be in a Jar.  2) `<applet code = "packageteste.Relogio.class" width="700"></applet>`  besides removing the `.class` as mentioned in the answer, be sure to specify a `height` for the applet.  It is a required attribute.